# How to pass rails data to JS or Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I want to get the article id from view.

```
<%= f.text_area :content, rows: 5, placeholder: 'input....', class: 'form-control',
    id: "tags", data: {article_id: @article.id } %>
```

then pass the article_id to coffeescript:

```
$ ->
  id = $("#tags").data('article_id')
  console.log "test-----------#{id}"
  $("#tags").autocomplete(
    source:  '/articles/' + id + '/autocomplete.json')
```

but output is:

```
test-----------undefined
```

How to pass rails data to JS or coffeescript?  How many ways to make it?

Thanks in advance!

as @muistooshort and @JoelL said: `data: {article_id: @article.id} will produce data-article-id="xxxx"`

html output:

```
<textarea rows="5" placeholder="input..." class="form-control" id="tags" data-article-id="{&quot;$oid&quot;:&quot;560017ddbd172d16d6000001&quot;}" name="comment[content]">
```

but I got the info from browser console log:

```
test----------[object Object]
```

it is not a string.

Comment: Try `$("#tags").data('article-id')`. I think rails convert `_` to `-` for data-attributes

Comment: Have you tried looking at the HTML to see what gets generated?

Comment: @muistooshort  `<textarea rows="5" placeholder="input..." class="form-control" id="tags" data-article-id="{&quot;$oid&quot;:&quot;560017ddbd172d16d6000001&quot;}" name="comment[content]">` ,but i got `test----------[object Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

You can add manually in you input because of containing `{}` in your `data-article-id`:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, rows: 5, placeholder: 'input....', class: 'form-control', id: "tags", 'data-article-id': @article.id %>
```

**For Jquery :**

Try [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get value attribute:

```
id = $("#tags").attr("data-article-id")
console.log "test-----------"+id
```

**For coffeescript :**

```
id = $("#tags").data("article-id")
console.log "test-----------"+id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the article id.

Comment: You're welcome. I have done to update my answer. Good. What a way did you do to get your id?

Answer (score 2):

`data: {article_id: @article.id}` will produce `data-article-id="theid"`

The following should work:

```
id = $("#tags").data('article-id')
```

Comment: you are right, but i got the `test----------[object Object]`, not a article id

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
id = $("#tags").data('article_id')
console.log "test-----------"+id
```

Comment: but Coffeescript can use `#{...}`